# error: zlib library and headers are required R on HPC

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, r, configure

System: 
`Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)`

I’ve installed zlib 1.2.11 on the home folder of a **Red Hat HPC** as part of the process for installing R base 3.4.0.

I get this error even after *successful* install of zlib

```
checking for inflateInit2_ in -lz... no
checking whether zlib support suffices... configure: error: zlib library and headers are required
```

I’ve checked R documentation and configure file for the issue of R requiring versions newer than 1.2.6 but not lexicographically recognizing 1.2.11 as >1.2.6, and that particular bug was patched in R 3.4.

I've reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076936/zlib-bz2-library-and-headers-are-requried-for-compiling-r) posted previously and the response is not relevant due to R 3.4 resolving that issue.

Any suggestion and/or input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests a change to the configure file which might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076936/zlib-bz2-library-and-headers-are-requried-for-compiling-r